# Lazy load laravel livewire and alpine js after page load

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm trying to lazy load livewire and alpine libs after page completely loads.
So, I have some progress in here, but, one issue, that alpine do no see livewire's methods, like `emitTo`
Here is my loader:

```
<script defer {{ $attributes }}>
    function loadLivewire() {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '{{ $fullAssetPath }}';
        script.setAttribute('data-turbo-eval', 'false');
        script.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-eval', 'false');
        document.body.append(script);

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.Livewire = new Livewire();
            window.Livewire.devTools({{ var_export($shouldDebug) }});
            window.livewire_app_url = '{{ $appUrl }}';
            window.livewire_token = '{{ $jsLivewireToken }}';
            window.Livewire.start();

            window.deferLoadingAlpine = function (callback) {
                window.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
                    callback();
                });
            };

            window.addEventListener("alpine:initializing", function () {
                window.Livewire.start();
            });

            loadAlpine();
        }, 50);
    }

    function loadAlpine() {
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.store('app', {
                sidebarOpen: false,
                selectedRepresentative: null,
                formOpen: null,
                modalOpen: null,
                recaptchaSitekey: null,
                addressesModalOpen: null,
                recallOpen: null
            });
        });

        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.4.1/dist/cdn.min.js';
        document.body.append(script);
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            loadLivewire();
        }, {{ $timeout }});
    });
</script>
```

All fine unless i click on some button that uses livewire logic, and then I got this:

```
VM128705:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emitTo')
    at eval (eval at generateFunctionFromString (cdn.js:380), <anonymous>:3:48)
    at cdn.js:391
    at tryCatch (cdn.js:415)
    at cdn.js:2595
    at handler3 (cdn.js:2054)
    at cdn.js:2075
    at cdn.js:2056
    at cdn.js:2097
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cdn.js:2056)
```